# How can a database parameter be used on `sp_addextendedproperty`?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I have found the MSDN definition and code examples of ['sp_addextendedproperty'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180047.aspx).  In Example A on that page, I see an example of how to add an extended property to a database.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
--Add a caption to the AdventureWorks2012 Database object itself.
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty 
@name = N'Caption', 
@value = 'AdventureWorks2012 Sample OLTP Database';
```

The thing that is immediately obvious is that you first have to declare a database context, and the stored procedure operates only within that database context.

If I wanted to add a database as a parameter, I suppose I could create a separate script that wraps around `sp_addextendedproperty` and sets the database context before executing the stored procedure.

For example

```
-- execute wrapper stored procedure
EXEC WrapperStoredProcedure @DatabaseName = N'Database name',
    @name = N'Extended property name',
    @value = N'Extended property value';
GO
```

In this case `WrapperStoredProcedure` probably uses Dynamic SQL to set the database context and execute `sp_addextendedproperty`.

Am I missing an obvious technique or convention that will allow me to declare the database as part of the `EXEC sp_addextendedproperty` statement, without having to create a separate wrapper scripts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The grammar for `exec` accepts a `@module_name_var` which allows the module name to be in a variable.

This does accepts three part names so the below does the trick.

```
DECLARE @DbName SYSNAME = 'AdventureWorks2012';
DECLARE @module_name_var NVARCHAR(500) = QUOTENAME(@DbName) + 
                                              '.sys.sp_addextendedproperty';

EXEC @module_name_var
  @name = N'Caption',
  @value = 'AdventureWorks2012 Sample OLTP Database';
```

Or alternatively having just reviewed the question again you may just need this anyway.

```
EXEC AdventureWorks2012.sys.sp_addextendedproperty
  @name = N'Caption',
  @value = 'AdventureWorks2012 Sample OLTP Database';
```